# События контролов в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = @"myClients\";
        String link = "ClientForm.aspx";
        String[] clients = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            LinkButton clientLink = new LinkButton();
            clientLink.ID = client;
            clientLink.Click += this.Redirect;
            clientLink.Text = client.Substring(path.Length, client.Length - path.Length) + "<br>";
            mainForm.Controls.Add(clientLink);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что событие `Click` не срабатывает (даже в назначенный метод не заходит). Метод `Redirect` формирует `POST` запрос и выполняет перенаправление на нужную страницу. Есть подозрение, что сборщик мусора контролы просто уничтожает. Как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Событие не сработает, если редирект произошел раньше, например в Page_Load... Что у вас там?

Comment: `Page_Load`  в обоих страницах пустой

Comment: @Андрей а как это он может сработать раньше, если я его нигде не вызываю? (я сейчас говорю про страницу, на которую должен выполнится редирект)

Comment: @Андрей и да, Вы правы. Действительно идет сразу редирект...
Если добавить свойство ` PostBackUrl`. Но если его убрать, то остаюсь на начальной странице и мои добавленные контролы исчезают, события не отрабатывают